# delete and update command not working.....program in asp.net2010, SQLYOG DATABASE 5.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net

in ths program my DISPLAY and ADD button is working but at the time of UPDATE and DELETE record it gives the exception error i.e  CHECK THE MANUAL THAT CORRESPONDS TO YOUR MYSQL SERVER FOR THE RIGHT SYNTAX.....
can you please correct my syntax...?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;database=dbconnect;user id=root;password=search;")
    Dim mydataset As New DataSet()
    Dim mydataadpter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
    Public query As String


    ' Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;database=dbconnect;user id=root;password=search;")

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        connection.Open()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_display_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_display.Click

        Dim mysql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select * from userinfo", connection)

        mydataadpter.SelectCommand = mysql
        mydataadpter.Fill(mydataset, "product")

        Try
            GridView1.DataSource = mydataset
            GridView1.DataBind()
            GridView1.DataMember = "product"
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_add_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click

        query = "INSERT INTO userinfo VALUES("
        query = query + txt_userid.Text + ",'" + txt_username.Text + "'," + txt_age.Text + ")"


        Dim MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
        Dim i As Integer = MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox("record is saved")
        Else
            MsgBox("record is not saved")
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_update_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_update.Click
        Try
            query = "UPDATE USERINFO SET username='" + txt_username.Text + "',"
            query = query + "age=" + txt_age.Text
            query = query + "WHERE userid=" + txt_userid.Text

            Dim mysqlcommand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            MsgBox(query)

            Dim i As Integer = mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If (i > 0) Then
                MsgBox("record is updated")
            Else
                MsgBox("record is not updated")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn_delete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_delete.Click
        Try
            query = "DELETE FROM userinfo WHERER userid=" + txt_userid.Text
            Dim mysqlcommand As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            MsgBox(query)

            Dim i As Integer = mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If (i > 0) Then
                MsgBox("record is deleted")
            Else
                MsgBox("record is not deleted")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are age and userid numeric integer fields?

Comment: age and id ate datatype int

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be syntactically correct, however, I would always use a parameterized query instead of a string concatenation. This will avoid Sql Injection and the quoting around the parameter value will be carried out by the framework code.

Try this for the update method

```
Try
    query = "UPDATE USERINFO SET username=@uname, age=@uage WHERE userid = @uid";
    Dim mysqlcommand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txt_username.Text))
    mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uage",Convert.ToInt32(txt_age.Text))
    mysqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid",Convert.ToInt32(txt_userid.Text))
    Dim i As Integer = mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("record is updated")
    Else
        MsgBox("record is not updated")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Another important thing to fix in your code is the global connection object. Don't do that. If one of your query fails for whatever reason you leave the connection open and that is a serious problem for the stability of your code.

```
Try
   query = "UPDATE USERINFO SET username=@uname, age=@uage WHERE userid = @uid";
   Using con = new MySqlConnection(.......)
   Using cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(......)
   End Using
   End Using
Catch ex As Exception
   ....
End Try
```

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) is critical to ensure a correct usage of expensive resources like a connection to the database and ensure a proper close and dispose of these kind of objects